# heroku recognizing the mongodb connection URL as file path

Tags: mongodb, heroku, environment-variables

heroku config:set DATABASE='mongodb+srv://milan_padhariya:@cluster0.3cghynn.mongodb.net/natours?retryWrites=true'

when i enter this the message i get back is:
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.